# Why a passed date gets converted to "Invalid Date" in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm obtaining the date from a input text field with the id *#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged* using JQuery. But when I assign it to the variable it is converted to a *Invalid Date* as shown in the image. Before assigning it has the correct value 'Mon Jan 01 2001'. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
debugger;
var startDate = null;
var isInvoiced = $("#isInvoiced").val();
if (isInvoiced.toLowerCase()=="true") {
    startDate = $("#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged") !== undefined ? $("#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged").val() : null;
} else {
    startDate = new Date($("#txtInvoiceStartDate").datepicker("getDate")).toDateString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as image

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE! Not pictures of code

Comment: @majidarif That seems to be additional information from debugger that shows resolved value of variable

Comment: If your input value is `Mon Jan 01 2001` then it's invalid format. Read about Date constructor more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string

Comment: `new Date("Mon Jan 01 2001")` works fine for me - is it an issue based on browser locale setting?

Comment: With `$("#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged") !== undefined` will *never*  be `undefined` - if you're checking if the input exists, use `if($("#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged").length)` - if you're checking if it has a value, use `if$("#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged").val() != "")` (or similar, check the .val())

Comment: Also, your edit isn't the same as the image was - there's new `new Date` on `#txtInvoiceStartDateUnchanged`

Comment: What are the parameters on your datepicker setup

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQueryUI datepicker?

Then it seems to work

```js
$("#txtInvoiceStartDate").datepicker(); // what do you have inside the () ?
$("#txtInvoiceStartDate").on("change",function() {
  const d = $("#txtInvoiceStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
  const startDate = new Date(d).toDateString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  console.log(d,startDate)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" id="txtInvoiceStartDate" />
```